# How to access access IQTypeFilter which has private access modifier in android asmack library?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I am developing chatting app using asmack. I need to filter incoming  IQ . I am using below code.

```
 PacketFilter filter = new IQTypeFilter(IQ.Type.SET); // or IQ.Type.GET etc. according to what you like to filter. 

connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() { 
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        // HERE YOU PUT YOUR CODE TO HANDLE THE IQ MESSAGE
    }
}, filter);
```

This show IQTypeFilter has private access. So i cant access here. How to solve this? Thanks in advance

My dependency jars are

compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.4'

```
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.4'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.4'
```

Comment: What error you are facing? post the code.

Comment: Error:(290, 68) error: incompatible types: StanzaFilter cannot be converted to Type

Comment: Post the full code and log.  Because,  error may rise for some other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

All required instances of `IQTypeFilter` are available as public static fields of the  class. See for example: [`IQTypeFilter.GET_OR_SET`](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/filter/IQTypeFilter.html#GET_OR_SET).

If you need more fine grained filtering you may want to look into [FlexibleStanzaTypeFilter](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/filter/FlexibleStanzaTypeFilter.html)